# Set up SOCKS5 proxy in OpenVPN on Android

Tags: proxy, openvpn

I want to set up a SOCKS5 proxy in OpenVPN. For example, this proxy: `5.196.58.136:17471`

I've read a few threads but couldn't fix it.

Can you please help me set up the SOCKS5 proxy on the OpenVPN Android app? How do I have to configure the .opvn file?